# Limiting results returned from the database

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I want to select every photo from my database, then display them grouped by month. I have that code here:

```
<?php
if (isset($_COOKIE['user_id'])) {
    if (!isset($_GET['user_id'])) {
        $user_id= $_COOKIE['user_id'];
    } else {
        $user_id= $_GET['user_id'];
    }
    $connect= mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "si");
    $query= "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE user_id= $user_id ORDER BY date DESC";

    $result= mysqli_query($connect, $query)
        or die('error with query');
    $date = "0";

    while ($row= mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        if ($date != $row['date']) {
            echo "<p> ".$row['date']."</p><br/>";
            $date = $row['date'];
        }
        echo '<img src="'.$row['picture']. '"/>' . "<br/>";
    }
}
?>
```

The only problem is that my code displays EVERY image from each month, this makes for an excessively large page. I want to limit my results to only 8 per month (or less if there isn't event 8 pictures for that month), then display a "show more..." link if there are more than 8. I know how to add a LIMIT to my initial query, but that won't work for this scenario. What can I do?

Here is how I want it to look:
[image: desired layout]

Answer (score 1):

add `LIMIT $start, $numToDisplay`

to your SQL statement, and use PHP to calculate the new values for the `$start` variable.

e.g. `$pageNum = $_GET["page"]` and 8 images per page means you can calculate that:

```
$numToDisplay = 8;
$start = ($pageNum-1)*$numToDisplay;
```

Comment: This is very wrong .. read the question again before you become down vote magnet

Comment: He said he wants 8 images on a page, if it creates links to go next and prev page in a gallery (which just goes to gallery.php?page=#), he would just need to adjust his SQL statement to get only the images he needs for that page @Baba

Comment: No. OP is looking for "limit my results to only 8 per month"

Comment: @nnichols Yes and that can easily be achieved by changing the SQL statement. I didn't include the full SQL statement but its obvious what I meant, I even explained it in my last comment. This way the code is much neater anyway.

Comment: @Ozzy - how do you think you can modify your SQL statement to return 8 posts per month? You could easily do 8 posts for a given month but not per month!

Comment: @nnichols ALTER TABLE posts ADD month INT; how hard was that?

Comment: @Ozzy - Not hard at all but it still won't enable you to select 8 posts per month in a single query by using LIMIT as you have suggested!

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is monitor picture count

```
$pickLimit = array ();
while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array ( $result ) ) {

    if ($date != $row ['date']) {
        echo "<p> " . $row ['date'] . "</p><br/>";
        $date = $row ['date'];
    }

    $pickLimit [$date] = isset ( $pickLimit [$date] ) ? $pickLimit [$date] : 0;
    if ($pickLimit [$date] > 7)
        continue;

    echo '<img src="' . $row ['picture'] . '"/>' . "<br/>";
    $pickLimit [$date] ++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be easily done using the php script whitch you already have and some css tricks, that are also used for creating an animated slider/carousel. Something like this:

```
<div id="carousel">
    <div id="slider">
    <?php foreach($images as $img) { ?>
        <div class="image">
            <img src="<?php echo $img; ?>" />
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

As for the css:

```css
#carousel {
    width: 900px; /* how much you need */
    height: 100px; /* how much you need */
    overflow: hidden;
}
#slider {
    width: auto;
    height: 100px;
}
.image {
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what is known as "greatest n per group" query. If you **[search on here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group)** there are many examples with different solutions. Here is one of them -

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
        tmp.*,
        @r := IF(@m=DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%Y%m'), @rank + 1, 1) rank,
        @m := DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%Y%m')
    FROM (
        SELECT *
        FROM posts
        WHERE user_id = $user_id
        ORDER BY date DESC
    ) tmp, (SELECT @m:=NULL, @r:=NULL) initvars
) tmp2
WHERE rank <= 8
```